# Rails Postgres Insert Duplicate Row Check Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, duplicates

I'm trying to detect and silently discard any duplicate INSERTs into a table, and if a dupe detected, return the ID (Primary Key) of the existing record. Otherwise, insert the record and return the new ID.

I can do this with either a RULE or a TRIGGER, however both have drawbacks.  Here's an example of my RULE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE territory_products_ignore_duplicate_inserts AS
ON INSERT TO territory_products
WHERE (EXISTS ( SELECT 1
       FROM territory_products tp
      WHERE tp.territory_id = NEW.territory_id AND tp.product_id = NEW.product_id)) DO INSTEAD SELECT tp.id
       FROM territory_products tp WHERE tp.territory_id = NEW.territory_id AND tp.product_id = NEW.product_id LIMIT 1;
```

Testing this in a SQL console or psql with an INSERT works fine.  If there's a dupe, it'll return the first existing record's id and not do the INSERT. Otherwise, it will go ahead with the INSERT. However, in Rails, it fails and returns this error:

ERROR:  cannot perform INSERT RETURNING on relation "territory_products"
HINT:  You need an unconditional ON INSERT DO INSTEAD rule with a RETURNING clause.

Moving to a TRIGGER, I try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function territory_products_ignore_dups() Returns Trigger
As $$
Begin
If Exists (
    Select id From territory_products tp
    Where tp.territory_id = NEW.territory_id And tp.product_id = NEW.product_id            
) Then
    Return NULL;
End If;
Return NEW;
End;
$$ Language plpgsql;

Create Trigger territory_products_ignore_dups
Before Insert On territory_products
For Each Row
Execute Procedure territory_products_ignore_dups();
```

This also works fine, except that I can't get it to return the existing ID, because of the Return NULL (which is required to disallow the INSERT).

Can anyone resolve either of these issues, so I get the result I'm looking for? (e.g. silently discard the INSERT in case of a dupe and return the ID of the existing record.  Or if the INSERT is successful, return the ID of the new record).

Comment: Why not just create a uniqueness validation in Rails and add a compound index in PG to safeguard against race conditions?

Comment: Do what max said.  Forces unique records only and you can just do an update if the record exists.

Comment: A uniqueness validation isn't full-proof in high-volume situations, since Rails is basically just running a SELECT to do the check before the INSERT.  Also, we'll sometime run update scripts on the DB, so would like to have the check be there, but without throwing exceptions everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique index to your database:

```
# migration file
add_index : territory_products, [:territory_id, :product_id], unique: true
```

In your logic look for the existing record or create if doesn't exist. It will raise an exception in case of a race condition. Just search again for the record.

```
#logic when finding/creating record
begin
  TerritoryProduct.where(territory_id: params[:territory_id], product_id: params[:product_id]).first_or_create!
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  # In case it already exists
  TerritoryProduct.where(territory_id: params[:territory_id], product_id: params[:product_id]).first
end
```

Comment: Ok, I'll buy that.  But I was trying to avoid raising exceptions, both in Rails, and during scripted inserts into the DB.  Just ignore duplicates and return an existing ID if there is one.  Is there no way to make either a Rule or Trigger do that?